# How come I have never seen an LTE sniffing tool on uplink?

Tags: wireless, sniffing, lte

I am trying to find whether it is possible to sniff LTE traffics.

However, I only found online about behaving as a fake base station (eNodeB) so devices will be forced to connect to you. Then you get info about other devices.

But I never find a completely passive sniffing tool.

There are downlink sniffing tool where you act as a benign user and search for basestation/cell signals. For example, openLTE and srsLTE.

But how come there is no such a tool to sniff traffic on the uplink (from user device to basestation)? Or there is one that I couldn't find?

Can some please explain this? I understand basic LTE frame structures and how they talk to the basestation.

Thanks ahead.

Comment: I do not understand why people downvote my question.. I asked this question for academic purpose..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main issue would be uplink synchronization. Each individual user has their own timing advance (based on physical distance from the cellular tower). This is so at the enB, the uplink transmissions are in sync from a physical perspective. As a sniffer, unless you're co-located with the enB, the uplink transmissions from different users will not arrived "in sync" with each other and hence decoding is basically impossible.